# How to install NVIDIA gpu on fedora 31

Tags: gpu, driver, nvidia, fedora

I installed fedora 31 (from windows), and I don't see it uses the GPU.
When I run:

```
$ lspci -v | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

and when I run:

```
$ lspci -v | grep NVIDIA 
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] (rev a1)
```

I have the GPU in my laptop, but how I install the GeForce GT 750M driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think that the driver isn't installed ?
have you tried : [Nvidia official driver for your gpu](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/145874/en-us) ?

if so, most laptop cards do not have dedicated gpu output instead the display is wired to the cpu's igpu so that the card can be put on a low power state when on battery. The dedicated gpu is proxied through the igpu which would explain why your nvidia card is not showing up as a vga controller.